# One Way to Source Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Ok quick summary is, I am trying to do a onewaytosource binding.

So explanation of my understanding of the  code. OneWaytoSource is the reverse of One Way binding. The target updates the source. So here my target is where I create the binding (so my textbox) my target property is the Foreground. My source is my menuItem and my source property is "IsEnabled".

The value converter is programmed in ConvertBack as this is the section that is meant for Onewaytosource or two way binding.

One of the textboxes:(I am planning to have this similar code on about 40 textboxes, which will disable my menuItem if the foreground is red)

```
 <TextBox x:Name="upperLimitMinimum" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=menuItem, Path=IsEnabled, Mode=OneWayToSource, Converter={StaticResource myColorErrorConverter}}"
```

This is my code for converter:

```
public class myColorErrorConverter : IValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {

        return null;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
        if (null != value)
        {
            string x = value.ToString();
            if (x == "Red")
            { return true; }

        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

My menuItem,

```
 <MenuItem x:Name="menuItem"   Header="Menu Item( Ctrl + E )" Command="{Binding MenuItem}"
```

What I expect to happen? When the textbox foreground turns red (which is controlled by a validation check, using a multivalue converter - not shown) The menuItem should become disabled. I have put a breakpoint on my converter and the code doesn't even enter the converter, so not really sure what is happening? Can someone shed some light on this?

After Clemens response, new code:

```
    <Style>
 <Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Value="True">
     <DataTrigger.Binding>
       <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverterColour}" >
     <Binding ElementName="upperLimitDefault" Path="Text" />
     <Binding ElementName="upperLimitMaximum"  Path="Text" />
     <Binding ElementName="upperLimitMinimum"  Path="Text" />
  </MultiBinding>
</DataTrigger.Binding>
 <Setter Property="TextBox.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>

          <Setter Property="TextBox.Foreground" Value="{Binding ElementName=MenuItem, Path=IsEnabled, Mode=OneWayToSource, Converter={StaticResource myColorErrorConverter}}" />
      </Style>
```

So now at start up the 2nd converter is accessed and disables/enable menuitem accordingly, but during application running, when textbox foreground changes, only the first converter is accessed and the colour will change but second converter isn't accessed

Comment: Any binding errors in the output window? Have you set the DataContext property?

Comment: @Lennart I have   this.DataContext = this; set in the mainWindow. as my understanding is I do not have to redo it in xaml if its set in code behind. I am not using MVVM structure. No binding errors in the output window, I am using other bindings that are working just fine, its just this one that I trying to do a reverse binding

Comment: That sounds alright. And it doesn't break into the `Convert()`either?

Comment: Is there another Binding on the Foreground property (presumably the one that uses the multi-value converter you're mentioning)?

Comment: @Clemens, Well the multivalue uses a multi binding which compares values from different objects, then uses a setter in the Style trigger, data trigger, to change the foreground in the textbox

Comment: @Lennart, doesn't break into Convert() either, correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment it seems that you're setting the `Foreground` property in a Style Setter. This assignment has a lower value precedence than the "local value" assigned by the Foreground Binding, and is therefore not effective.

You may replace

```
<TextBox Foreground="{Binding ...}" ... />
```

by a Style Setter like this (or add it to an already defined TextBox Style):

```
<TextBox ...>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ...}" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

For reference, see [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi Clemens, it does seem to be a precedence issue, although cant get it to fully work just yet, my converter is only getting accessed at start up but not when putting values into the textboxes

Comment: It's difficult to help you with that. You haven't shown anything about how you actually set the Foreground property.

Comment: I should probably post a new question, as now the one way to source binding is working, just having other issues, ill mark your answer as correct, as you solved the initial problem, thanks